# Is this the correct equation for the four force on a system in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, vectors

Four velocity is the derivative of spacetime coordinates with respect to proper time, and four acceleration is the derivative of four velocity with respect to proper time.  Also the four force is the rest mass multiplied by the four acceleration.  The four velocity always have a magnitude of $c$, so the magnitude of four velocity doesn't change but the direction of four velocity can.

I know one way to understand special relativity is through wick rotation.  If I consider what constant proper acceleration in euclidean spacetime would mean, it would imply moving through spacetime in a semi circle.  If the magnitude of the spacetime velocity is constant and the world line of an object is a semi circle then the spacetime acceleration is perpendicular to the spacetime velocity.  I can think of a non uniform acceleration as consisting of constant proper accelerations over infinitesimal increments of spacetime.  If I think of one object as made up of multiple objects with different spacetime velocities, then if I simply add the four forces acting on the smaller objects, I may not get a four force that is perpendicular to the four velocity of the system, implying that four forces don't add in the way ordinary vectors do.

In order to try to derive the way to add spacetime forces in euclidean spacetime I considered a right triangle with the vector C for the hypotenuse being the sum of spacetime forces if we just added them like ordinary vectors, the vector for one of the legs A proportional to the sum I just mentioned and in the same direction as the spacetime velocity of the system, and the vector for the other leg B being the actual spacetime force on the system.

If I denote the spacetime velocity for the system $\vec{U}$, and the sum of spacetime forces if I pretend that the spacetime forces add like ordinary vectors

$$\vec{C}=\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}$$

then the vector for the leg that is proportional to the above summation, but in the same direction as the spacetime velocity would be

$$\vec{A}=\left(\vec{U}*\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}\right)*\frac{\vec{U}}{\left|\left|\vec{U}\right|\right|^2}$$

so then I can use vector subtraction to find the vector for the other leg and take

$$\vec{B}=\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}-\left(\vec{U}*\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}\right)*\frac{\vec{U}}{\left|\left|\vec{U}\right|\right|^2}$$

So now I'm thinking that in Minkowski Spacetime if I denote the four force on a system as $\vec{F_S}$, the four velocity of a system as $\vec{U_S}$, the four forces on the bodies making up the system as $\vec{F_i}$, and the speed of light as $c$ then the equation would be

$$\vec{F_S}=\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}-\left(\vec{U_S}*\sum_{i=1}^n\vec{F_i}\right)*\frac{\vec{U_S}}{c^2}$$

Trying out this equation in euclidean spacetime I find that the dot product of the four velocity and the four force on the system is always $0$ indicating that they are perpendicular.  My question is, in special relativity, is this equation correct?  If not what is the correct equation?

Answer (score 0):

No, the equation is not correct. Four-forces simply add.

> If I think of one object as made up of multiple objects with different spacetime velocities, then if I simply add the four forces acting on the smaller objects, I may not get a four force that is perpendicular to the four velocity of the system, implying that four forces don't add in the way ordinary vectors do.

This is not a correct implication. There is no need for the four-force to be perpendicular to the four velocity in general. In the case that they are not perpendicular it means that the system’s mass is changing. Remember that the system’s mass is not necessarily the sum of the masses of the smaller objects.

> Also the four force is the rest mass multiplied by the four acceleration.

The four force is the rate of change of the four momentum with respect to proper time. If the mass is not changing then this is true, but where the mass is changing the relationship between four-force and four-acceleration is more complicated

Comment: Is it only the case for objects made of smaller objects that the four force can be not perpendicular to four velocity, or can this also be the case for objects that can't be subdivided as well?

Comment: All of the fundamental particles we know have a fixed mass.